# HTML 5 Canvas Scene Graph Recomendations

Tags: html, canvas, graph, scene

Let me tell you my requirements and see if anyone has some recommendations...

1. Cross browser (as much as realistically possible)
2. Be able to drag labeled objects around the screen (boxes and circles with labels in them)
3. Attach objects to each other by drawing lines (arrows) between them
4. Be able to "pick" any object on the screen (including those lines from #3)

I am not looking for a tool that just gives me all of that, I can program the logistics on top of it.  But is seems to me I have basically described a scene graph.  I know of cakejs - but was wondering of any other solutions out there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the game engines on https://gist.github.com/768272?  Some of them purport to have scene graph implementations.  I am not familiar with the scene-graph ones so I cannot give you recommendations, but hopefully there are some useful things on that list....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UmlCanvas might do what you need. It has a data definition language to describe graphs and relationships as well as a canvas to render those entities. Unfortunately it looks like something open-sourced by a startup before they decided to pursue other interests.

http://umlcanvas.org

http://blog.thesoftwarefactory.be

Comment: umlcanvas.org is 404 (for the next guy that clicks on it)

Comment: The company seems to have completely folded.  I think this is the final snapshot of the code: https://github.com/christophevg/UmlCanvas

Comment: All you links are dead. Please remove this answer.